# Why the log likelihood is positive in some cases

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, model, scale-parameter

I have a log likelihood that looks like the following.

$$ \log(p(Z|\Theta)) = -\sum_{p = 1}^{N} \left[ L \log\left(\pi\left(A F(p, \Theta) + \sigma_n^2\right) \right) + \frac{\sum_{l = 1}^{L} Z_l(p) }{A F(p, \Theta) + \sigma_n^2} \right]  $$

It comes from an exponential distribution. The observations are $Z_l(p)$ and $A F(p, \Theta) + \sigma_n^2$ is the model. However, the scale factor $A$ and additive factor $\sigma_n^2$ are estimated empirically or from prior knowledge before computing this likelihood.

Some real world measurements $Z$ do give me positive log-likelihood values. I want to have a quantitative measure of how good my data fits the measurements. That is why I thought of looking at the likelihood of all the different real world measurements. So, a measurement giving a log-likelihood value close to $0$ (but negative) is more fitted to my model than a measurement that gives a log-likelihood value far from $0$ (but negative).

However, now that I also have positive values for log-likelihood, I am confused how to say if the measurements fit my model.

Sometimes, by visual inspection, I find that a log likelihood of $-2000$ reconstruct my data better than a log-likelihood of 50 for example. To emphasize again, this is from a visual inspection.

Any input is appreciated.

My suspect: I think $A$ and $\sigma_n^2$ are the reason for which probably it is more than $0$. Am I right? If yes, how can I say something about my estimation (not just with visual inspection, but also from likelihood).